I can't attach the head to the body
I have been struggling for a long time, I can't attach the head to the body. I have tried many things, but it still looks crooked. Help, good people! I would be very grateful if you could help, here is a link to the file.


Please give us more details. What do you want to do with the model? Is it just a pose or an animation or a 3D print? Do you want to paint/texture it?

hi, i want to attach the head to the body so that there are no seams, since i will print it on a 3D printer later

First thing you gotta do is get the two parts matching a bit closer in terms of geo density. The top one is way too high-res right now.

A decimate modifier set to .1 worked for me.

Then get rid of this part. I just select these faces and then alternate between "Select > Linked Flat Faces" and Ctrl + NumpadPlus to quickly get this section selected and deleted.


Then use your knife tool to cut a line across to remove this bit, it's kind of in the way and awkward.

Then just press V to rip it out, then L to select that linked piece and delete it.

Then i select the boundary loops, to get that loop selected quickly. Looks like there's some other non-manifold geometry you'll need to figure out later, deselect that.

Then do a Ctrl+NumpadPlus a couple times to increase this selection, then merge by distance to clean up the random small verts lingering around. Use a high-ish distance value to really hammer em down. (I also used Ctrl+A to apply scale)

You'll prolly want to go back through and manually clean up random stuff like this that didn't get caught by the weld.

After Alt+C to collapse verts.

Also get rid of these weird stretched edges.

After that I run LoopTools > Relax on the boundary edge to smooth it out.

After that you Ctrl+J to join the objects, then select those edge loops and bridge them.

It's gonna be janky right off the bat, so we need to go into sculpt mode to clean it up. This is one of the times you want to use DynTopo, use these settings:

Set the strength to zero and brush around to add in geo where needed.


After that it's just good old 3D Artistry, smooth it out, use the crease/pinch brush to sculpt it together and make them look more natural.
Final Result:


Thank you very much. This is a great method, easier than it looks. Thanks again!

@Independer Glad I could help! Alot of times it do be like that. When in doubt, model it out.
